# Risk Function as Expected Value of Loss Function Evaluation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZauH.png

I'm interested in part (g), specifically.  I know that the risk function is the expected value of the loss function, but I'm confused as to how to evaluate it.  When I replace $\theta$ with $\tilde \theta$, I get an expression which is pretty difficult to evaluate the expected value of... so perhaps I'm not going about this the right way.  How would you calculate this risk function?

Comment: Try to replace $t$ with $\tilde \theta$ and leave $\theta$ as is.

Comment: I tried that, but I still end up with some pretty nasty results.  Is that really how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: If you expand it, it is just a quadratic expression in $\bar{X}$. $E[\bar{X}]$ is well known, and $E[\bar{X}^2] = Var[\bar{X}] + E[\bar{X}]^2$. Does this help?

Comment: I already knew that, I was just saying that my final answer didn't simplify nicely or anything.  It's a fairly massive expression.

Answer (score 0):

Find risk function for $\bar X$. 
$$\mathbb E[X_1]=\frac{1-p}{p}=\theta, \ \text{Var}[X_1]= \frac{1-p}{p^2}=\theta^2+\theta.
$$ 
Then
$$\mathbb E[\bar X]=\theta, \ \text{Var}[\bar X]= \frac{\theta^2+\theta}n.$$
Risk runction for $\bar X$ is
$$
\mathbb E\left[\frac{(\bar X-\theta)^2}{\theta^2+\theta}\right] = \frac{\text{Var}[\bar X]}{\theta^2+\theta} = \frac1n.
$$
Find risk function for $\tilde \theta=\frac{n+1}{n}\bar X$. 
$$
\mathbb E\left[\frac{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\bar X-\theta\right)^2}{\theta^2+\theta}\right] =\frac{\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\bar X-\theta\right)^2\right]}{\theta^2+\theta}=\frac{\text{Var}\left[\frac{n+1}{n}\bar X-\theta\right]+\left(\mathbb E\left[\frac{n+1}{n}\bar X-\theta\right]\right)^2}{\theta^2+\theta} = \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}\text{Var}\left[\bar X\right]+\frac{\theta^2}{n^2}}{\theta^2+\theta} =\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^3}+\frac{\theta}{n^2(\theta+1)}
$$